# App Suddenly Crashing Roku

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error, runtime-error, roku

Sorry if this isn't terribly descriptive, but lately my app has been crashing overnight. I usually leave it running during the day and it's just fine but if I leave it on all night and come back the next morning to check on it I find the Roku device at the home screen. The debugger doesn't offer up much information other than the following but I'm not sure how to make sense of it. I look at the lines (?) mentioned and don't see anything off in the code. Any ideas? I'm testing on the 3500X - Roku Stick software version 7.2.0 build 4100-09. Much appreciation.

```
BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(185)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(186)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(187)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(188)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(189)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(190)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(191)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(192)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(193)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(194)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(195)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(196)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(197)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(198)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(199)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(200)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(201)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(202)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(203)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(204)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(205)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(206)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(207)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(208)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(209)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(210)

BrightScript Debugger> Syntax Error. (compile error &h02) in $LIVECOMPILE(211)
```

Answer (score 1):

The app is not "crashing suddenly". Roku kills apps that it judges inactive after a few (two?) hours. Why are you leaving app overnight, what is it supposed to do?

Never mind the console, that's confusing you - what you see is un-related, it's left-over from interactive session you had before, the error messages are from what you typed back then. Notice how mis-aligned are the diagnostics, on the same line with the prompt.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. It's a music app. I left it on all night again last night and it didn't get axed this time around. And I usually leave it on over more than 2 hours, not interacting with it at all, just letting it play and it never crashes.

Comment: Alas i don't know the exact timeout conditions - just have seen a vague note by s/o from RokuCo that apps get terminated after some period of time. Bring your question to https://forums.roku.com/viewforum.php?f=34 , maybe more info will be revealed

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be a memory leak somewhere. That's pretty easy to do these days. Check if all your tasks are terminating.